# uploading image through ajax jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using Mustache JS for creating a template named 'addUser1' for displaying purpose. When I run this only the image location is being posted to the server, not the image itself.  What is the error here?

> this is the code

```
$('#add-user').on('click', function(){

    var myform = document.getElementById("form_user");
    var data = new FormData(myform );
    $.each($('#user_photo')[0].files, function(i, file) {
        data.append('file', $('#user_photo')[0].files[0]);
    });

    var user = {
        user:{
        firstname: $firstname.val(),
        lastname: $lastname.val(),
        gender: $gender.val(),
        address1: $address1.val(),
        address2: $address2.val(),
        contact_number: $contact_number.val(),
        email: $email.val(),
        password: $password.val(),
        city: $city.val(),
        state: $state.val(),
        country: $country.val(),
        user_photo: $user_photo.val(),
        }
    };

    $.ajax({

        headers: {
                   'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                  },

        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://13.229.164.32/users.json',
        data: data,
        cache : false,
        processData: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache : false,
        success: function(newUser){

        addUser1(newUser);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
          alert("erorr")
        }

    });


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this,

```
var formData = new FormData(); 
var totalFiles = document.getElementById("ProfilePhoto").files.length; 
for (var i = 0; i < totalFiles; i++) 
{ 
     var file = document.getElementById("ProfilePhoto").files[i]; formData.append("ProfilePhoto", file);
} 
            $.ajax({ 
                type: "POST",
                url: 'http://13.229.164.32/users.json', 
                data: formData, dataType: 'json',
                contentType: false, processData: false,
                success: function (response) 
                { 
                   addUser1(response);
                }, 
                error: function (error) { } 
            });
```

I hop this will help you.

Comment: please read this https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: So this answer will helpful to other

Answer (score 0):

`.val()` returns the value of the HTML element; for an image, that's the `src` attribute. You might want to convert the data to `base64` and then try saving it. The overhead will be huge, but that's one of the ways I can think of.

Something like:

```
<img id="testImage" src="https://test.com/image.png" />
<canvas id="baseCanvas" />
```

Then, in JS, you can have the following:

```
const canvas  = document.getElementById( 'baseCanvas' );
const context = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
const image   = document.getElementById( 'testImage' );
context.drawImage( image, 10, 10 );
const data = canvas.toDataURL();

console.log( data );
```